# How to get multi field form data in email body

Tags: php, forms

Complete newbie at PHP. help.

I have written a large "join the club" form with 15 fields. the first 10 fields are required. last 5 are optional.

Each field has ID and names. name="fname" name="lname", for each field. (see below)___

```
<!-- FORM STARTS HERE -->
       
<form id="appliform" name="applform" method="post"
      action="joinformscripts/test11.php"
      enctype="text/plain" > 
<!-- php code still in progress. test memb.php --->

<label for="fname">*First Name:</label><br>
     <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" required><br>
      
<label for="lname">*Last Name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" required><br>
      
<label for="bizname">*Business Name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="bizname" name="biz" required><br>
      
<label for="bizadd">*Business Mailing Address:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="bizadd" name="bizadd" required> <br>
      
<label for="city">*City:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="city" name="city" required> <br>
      
<label for="state">*State:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="state" name="state" required> <br> 
      
<label for="zip">Zip:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" required> <br> 
      
 <label for="bizphone">*Business Phone:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="bizphone" name="bizphone" required> <br>  

<label for="celphone">Personal Phone:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="celphone" name="celphone"> <br>
      
 <label for="email">*Email:</label><br>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br>       
        
  
<hr>

<h5>Complete this information if you are also paying for an Associate Membership. </h5>
         
<label for="fname">Associate First Name:</label><br>
     <input type="text" id="afname" name="afname"><br>
      
<label for="lname">Associate Last Name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="alname" name="alname"><br>
    
<label for="bizphone">Associate Business Phone:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="abizphone" name="abizphone" > <br>  

<label for="celphone">Associate Personal Phone:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="acelphone" name="acelphone"> <br>
             
<label for="aemail">Associate Email:</label><br>
      <input type="aemail" id="aemail" name="aemail"><br> 
 
 <hr>    
  <p>test 11 @ 6.00p</p>     
 <!-- SEND BUTTON Submit using secure POST DATA button  
when sent, opens remit payment page (in script)-->
    
 <input type="submit" value="submit application" ><br>
   <input type="reset" value="clear form">
  <br>
    <br>
    
    <p>Please remit payment on the next page.</p>
    
</form>    <!-- END MEMBERSHIP FORM with script action -->
```

### PHP script.

```
 <?php
// test 11
// after submit, goes to Remit page for payment: yes. //
// receive email with content in body:  NO   //

$email_to = "membership@xxxx.org";
$email_from = "membership@xxxx.org";


$reply_to = $_POST["email"];
$headers = "submitted by: .$mailfrom .$fname .$lname ";



$email_subject = "New Member Application Form (phptest8) revised 6.00pm thursday dec 10";
$headers = "From: " . $email_from . "\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $reply_to . "\n";

// NOT CAPTURING form variables.
    
 //This needs to send all the fields in the form on Join page.   
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "membership@efwba.org"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['fname'];
    $last_name = $_POST['lname'];
    $subject = "Membership Form submission";
    
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " 
    wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "my information " . $fname . "\n\n" . $fname . $lname . $biz . $bizadd . $city . $state . $zip . $bizphone . $celphone . $email . $afname . $alname . $abizphone . $acelphone. $aemail.  $_POST['message'];
    }

   
    
//Send the email. If the email is sent we will go to a REMIT PAYMENT page, if there is an error we will display a brief message.

    ini_set("sendmail_from", $email_from);
    $sent = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers, $email_from);
    
    
    if ($sent)
    {
    header("Location:/joinformscripts/thank-you-for-joining.html");
        
    } else {
    echo "There has been an error submitting your application. Please go back one page to verify all data has been entered correctly.";
    }



// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
___
```

The host server -goDaddy, Cpanel- processes the php file and sends the email to the "Membership@"  account.
After the form submits, it redirects to the Payment page, that part works!

**However, I am NOT getting the field data inside the body of the email.**

I see the starter line, but not what the applicant entered for contact info.

I want the body/ data to be a simple format, so I can copy it all and drop into a spreadsheet (for club mail merge printing)
It does not need to show the data labels.

I want to see this data in the email body:
"I want to join your organization!"
fname lname
biz
bizaddress
city state zip
bizphone
celphone
bizemail

****QUESTION**: what is the simplest method to capture each field into email_body?**

Thank you!

Comment: Update your question with one specific problem. What you have tried, what is the issue you have got and so on. https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: `where do spaces and dots and double quotes go?` ..... Unanswerable as you show no code. Edit your question and include the applicable source code, preferably the html form and the PHP backend script.

Comment: I haven't gone through the whole code, but I could see you have added the condition `if($_POST['submit'])` but in the submit button you missed the name attribute. Change it to `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit application" >` and give a try.